# Prevent collapse of several floating left tables

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-table

I have several floating left tables wrapped into a div. The question is how to prevent/avoid these tables to collapse when screen resolution is low. My code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .data{
                float:left;
                clear: none;
            }
            td{
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="data">
                <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table class="data">
                <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table class="data">
                <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table class="data">
                <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table class="data">
                <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table class="data">
                <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table class="data">
                <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table class="data">
                <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I cannot use DIVs for the data itself, table usage is a must. In addition number of generated tables is dynamic, i.e. I can have 1, 10 or 100 tables there depending of amount of database data.

Comment: I guess the tables has much more columns and content as in your example?

Comment: Yes, they are, this code just shows the concept used into the page.

Comment: IMO you can only adjust the `font-size` for serverals screen solutions via media queries. Complex tables in responsive designs is a difficult mission.